# Merging two SVG Paths: Open Bezier and Line

Tags: svg, inkscape, libreoffice-draw

The merge portion of my question has been well answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051988/4272389 which resolved two *LineGradients* with one line node and the other a path node.

In my situation I have an Open Bezier path and a Line path and am not sure if that answer for LineGradient still applies

```
<g class="com.sun.star.drawing.OpenBezierShape">
 <g id="id5">
  <rect class="BoundingBox" stroke="none" fill="none" x="7699" y="4699" width="303" height="203"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(52,101,164)" d="M 7700,4900 C 7816,4847 7964,4842 8000,4700"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="com.sun.star.drawing.LineShape">
 <g id="id6">
  <rect class="BoundingBox" stroke="none" fill="none" x="8799" y="6099" width="30" height="3"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(52,101,164)" d="M 8800,6100 L 8827,6100"/>
 </g>
</g>
```

Using the viewbox transform procedure suggested in the prior answer (https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform), would the merge entail the expanding the bounding box then using the origin from id5 and then converting id6 coordinates into relative values inside the expanded box I call "merged"?:
My arithmetic expression is pseudo code to indicate my transform formula)

```
<g id="merged">
  <rect class="BoundingBox" stroke="none" fill="none" x="8799" y="6099" width="300+(8799-7699)+30" height="203+(6100-4699)+3"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(52,101,164)" d="M 7700,4900 C 7816,4847 7964,4842 8000,4700 m [(8799-7699) + (8800-8799), (6099-4699) + (6100-6099)] l (8827-8799),(6100-6099)"/>
</g>
```

Reason: The fragments were drawn with LibreOffice draw and the paths were joined using Inkscape, but I could not do so fully, so I have to manually close the paths in the final Inkscape result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths can have multiple subpaths. So most of the time, you can just append them together, like so:

```
d="M 7700,4900 C 7816,4847 7964,4842 8000,4700 M 8800,6100 L 8827,6100"/>
```

The only thing you need to watch for is if the move command in the second path is a lower-case `m`.  In a single path, starting with an `m` (relative move) is an error, and it is interpreted as a `M` (absolute move).  But if you append it to another path, a lower-case `m` would be valid.  So you would need to change the `m` to an `M` when appending.

As for the bounding box, you just need to do a "union" operation. In other words finding the min and max X and Y coords of the two rectangles.

```
Box 1: minX="7699" minY="4699" maxX="7699 + 303 = 8002" maxY="4699 + 203 = 4902"
Box 2: minX="8799" minY="6099" maxX="8799 + 30 = 8829" maxY="6099 + 3 = 6102"

Union: minX="7699" minY="4699" maxX="8829" maxY="6102"
Box:   x="7699" y="4699" width="1130" height="1403"
```

So the merged paths should be:

```
<g id="merged">
  <rect class="BoundingBox" stroke="none" fill="none" x="7699" y="4699" width="1130" height="1403"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(52,101,164)" d="M 7700,4900 C 7816,4847 7964,4842 8000,4700 M 8800,6100 L 8827,6100"/>
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was afraid that the Bezier curve coordinates might also need scaling when the bounding box changed in size. Maybe in the alternate case, when the curve came after the line element and then needed relative values for the curve? (But I'm finding out reversing the direction of the drawing and the downward graphic Y coordinate is the worse of the monsters).